# informix 12.10 create multiple stored procedures with single file

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

I have two stored procedure : sub_Proc and Proc
But when I try to create them in a single file, I get into trouble

```
--file1.sql

CREATE PROCEDURE sub_Proc()
 --do Something;
End  PROCEDURE 

CREATE PROCEDURE Proc() --Syntax Error!
CALL sub_Proc();
End  PROCEDURE
```

I get a syntax error,
of course they can be made in two separate files,
but can they be made in a single file?
Can anybody help?

Comment: You are missing semi-colons ( `;` ) closing each procedure definition. Generally a  good practice to close all your SQL statements with a semi-colon.

Comment: @LuísMarques: now it works